# Error: origin_mismatch when using Google calendar API with port 444

Tags: javascript, api, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am getting an error origin_mismatch message when I try to use the Google Calendar API through another site that uses a different port.

The code doesn't return an error when the API request is sent from http://original.domain.edu.

However, the code returns the above title error when the API request is sent from https://original.domain.edu:444 (which is the secure login port that the app uses).

I've added both https://original.domain.edu:444 and https://original.domain.edu to my OAuth client in my API console but the same error is still occurring. Can someone offer some help on this?

```
var exportCalendarToGoogle = function() {

var clientId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
var scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';
var apiKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

var withGApi = function() {
  console.log("gapi loaded");
  setTimeout(function() {
      gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
      gapi.auth.init(checkAuth);
    }, 500);
}

var checkAuth = function() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scope, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
}

var handleAuthResult = function(authResult) {
    if(authResult) {
        gapi.client.load("calendar", "v3", exportCalendar);
    } else {
        alert("Authentication failed: please enter correct login information.");
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Your origins don't match. An allowed origin will mismatch for a different scheme (http vs. https) and/or port (80 vs 444), add your allowed origin exactly as it is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a server side file to act as a proxy/bridge to get around JS Origin issues.

eg: `var scope = "https://original.domain.edu:444/proxy.php";`

```
<?php 
//proxy.php file
echo file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar?' . http_build_query($_GET) ); 
?>
```

Comment: sorry would've given you the bounty but didn't check the answer until I got a notification that it expired.